# control access type or lock external swf related with main scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external

I ask, i have a as3 player that call external swf. I use mouse_move event in a swf and another  swf has button. I want that lock swf interaction. In main, user can t use button in swf or can t working objects has mouse_move event.

How to lock interaction/change access type external swf with main player?

Thanx all reply

Answer (score 0):

Set on that child SWF - `mouseChildren = false;`

Like:

```
    var loader : Loader = new Loader();

    loader.load( new URLRequest( "child.swf" ) );

    this.addChild( loader );

    loader.mouseChildren = false;
```

This will disallow any mouse interaction with loaded movie.